# How to center an icon Search everywhere in RubyMine?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

How to center the "search everywhere" icon in Rubymine? she is always on the right in the corner, but I would like her in the center.

RubyMine 2023.3

In RubyMine 2019.2.4 I can do it.

Answer (score -1):

Please right-click on main toolbar, select "Customize Toolbar" and move "Search Everywhere" from "Right" to "Center".

Comment: this does not work. Please show me on video how you do this? do you have the latest version RubyMine?

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot from "Customise Main Tool bar" along with main toolbar shown?

Comment: Please try with the following settings https://prnt.sc/x2qzKjsq--Jx Works fine for me in build 2023.3.2 (see Help | About)

Comment: @y.bedrov watch this https://prnt.sc/QECq1KGTY7O0, as you can see Search everywhere before Setting, but in toolbar Search everywhere on the right, after setting.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I don't have such settings. where does Center Right and Left come from? you can see my options here https://prnt.sc/QECq1KGTY7O0

Comment: I have classic UI